# JMS serialize bundle @exclude annotation not working

Tags: php, symfony

My entity FosUserBundle

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Exclude;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\Group;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @Exclude
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $balance = 0;
```

But if I try serialize App\Entity\User object:

```
$this->get('jms_serializer')->serialize($user, 'json');
```

It returned me ID field!

```
 {
  "id": 1,
  "username": "admin",
  "username_canonical": "admin",
  "email": "admin",
  "email_canonical": "admin",
  "enabled": true,
  "salt": "o12yxgxp3vkk0w4sck80408w8s8o84s",
  "password": "$2y$13$o12yxgxp3vkk0w4sck804uSVjSMSB1W0qwEjunGTHomBqqoGvkW9G",
  "last_login": "2016-02-28T17:28:19+0300",
  "locked": false,
  "expired": false,
  "roles": [
    "ROLE_ADMIN"
  ],
  "credentials_expired": false
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of FOSUserBundle serializer rules, your exclusion strategies will not work.

To make your exclusion used, you need to tell JMSSerializer to squash the FOSUB serialisation.

In your `config.yml`, add the following:

```
jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        auto_detection: true # Don't forget this line
        directories:
            FOSUB:
                namespace_prefix: FOS\UserBundle
                path: %kernel.root_dir%/serializer/FOSUB
```

Then, create the file `app/serializer/FOSUB/Model.User.yml` and paste the following into:

```
FOS\UserBundle\Model\User:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
```

Now, all inherited properties are excluded, you can expose what you want.

Adapt it to your need if you want keep some properties, or redefine them in your entity.

See the corresponding issue [#78](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/78).

**Update**

For your not working @Expose annotation, add the `auto_detection` like in my previous example.

If this doesn't solve the problem, use the `@Groups` annotation and do something like this :

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @JMS\Groups({"user"})
 */
private $balance = 0;
```

Change your controller like this:

```
use JMS\Serializer\SerializationContext;

$context = SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('user'));
$serializer->serialize($user, 'json', $context);
```

And it should works.

Keep in mind that this problem exists only because your User entity extends a class that already have serializer rules.

Comment: Thx!!!
Okay and if I wanna seriallize settings for some entity class what I need do for that?
I want to show balance field from AppBundle\Entity\User class...

Comment: The config I given you disable the mapping of FOSUB, now the serialiser mapping of your own entity will be used, so you can use what you do actually to expose or exclude fields of your entity. You will maybe need to set auto_detection to true in the jms_serializer.metadata config

Comment: Just add the `@Expose` annotation on your field `balance` in your own class. All fields are excluded by default, just expose what you want using @expose, @groups and other strategies.

Comment: Don't forget that you can accept answer when your question is done, at your appreciation of course.

Comment: `@Expose` before `$balance` not working for me 
I add auto_detection is true in configuration

Comment: Look at my edit. don't forget to clear your cache between all tries. I also added the good detection config, be sure you have the same in yours.

Comment: Thx very much! 
But how I can use this context in FosRestBundle?
I use jms_serializer service here for example...
In project this inject automaticly executed...

Comment: You're welcome . You have an annotation called `View` in FOSRest. Use it like `@View(serializerGroups={"user"})` . See http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/view_response_listener.html

Comment: I've add `@View(serializerGroups={"user"}) ` before method controller and add `/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"user"})
     * @Expose
     */
    private $balance = 0;` but not resolved

Comment: Don't forget to import the annotation, if you encounter problems with the FOSRest view, maybe you should open another question :)  Look at the link I given to you, there is an example of how manually set the SerializationContext to your FOSREST view

Answer (score 0):

```
        $serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()
            ->setSerializationContextFactory(function () {
                return \JMS\Serializer\SerializationContext::create()
                    ->setSerializeNull(true)
                    ;
            })
            ->setDeserializationContextFactory(function () {
                return \JMS\Serializer\DeserializationContext::create()
                    ->setSerializeNull(true)
                    ;
            })
            ->setAnnotationReader($annotationReader)
            ->setPropertyNamingStrategy(new SerializedNameImportantThanPropertyNameStrategy())
            ->build();
```

Ignoring some parent classes: CComponent, CModel, CActiveRecord

```
        $class = new \ReflectionClass($serializer);
        $property = $class->getProperty('navigator');
        $property->setAccessible(true);
        $navigator = $property->getValue($serializer);

        $class = new \ReflectionClass($navigator);
        $property = $class->getProperty('metadataFactory');
        $property->setAccessible(true);
        $metadataFactory = $property->getValue($navigator);

        $class = new \ReflectionClass($metadataFactory);
        $property = $class->getProperty('loadedClassMetadata');
        $property->setAccessible(true);
        $property->setValue($metadataFactory, [
            'CComponent' => new NullMetadata(new \stdClass()),
            'CModel' => new NullMetadata(new \stdClass()),
            'CActiveRecord' => new NullMetadata(new \stdClass()),
        ]);
```